# CSS center is working on two pages but not the other

Tags: css

The CSS centering works on this page: http://www.paragondictionary.info/A.html

But not on this page: http://www.paragondictionary.info/C.html

Both HTML pages are using the same CSS link so I don't know why the centering is not working on one page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tip for the long term... name classes for what things _are_, not how things _look_. Your `<div class="center">` seems to be the container for the dictionary entries, so call it `<div class="entries">` and then style it just like you are already doing. But next month, when you decide it should be flush-left, you don't wind up with class=center that is _not_ centered, or you don't have to go through every page on your site to rename the class so it makes sense. Say "These are entries" in the page structure, then say "Entries are centered" in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working on the second one is because you forgot to add the

```
<div class="center">

</div>
```

that surrounds the definition list in the body

If you look at the first page in view source, you can see on line 20 there's a class called

```
 .center
```

That is used to presumably, center the content.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to use {div class="center"} in the second page.